# ionic3: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, build.gradle

I have this error:

> Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>   Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

when i have run

> ionic cordova run android

this is info ionic:

> cli packages: (AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v6.11.1
npm               : 2.15.12
OS                : Windows 7
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\med\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

package.json:

```
{
      "name": "wetry",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "author": "Ionic Framework",
      "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
        "@ionic-native/base64": "^4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^4.6.0",
        "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^4.5.3",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
        "com-badrit-base64": "^0.2.0",
        "com.synconset.imagepicker": "~2.1.8",
        "cordova-plugin-analytics": "^1.4.3",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^5.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
        "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.2.1",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.1.8",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^4.0.3",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "ng2-cordova-oauth": "0.0.8",
        "rxjs": "5.5.2",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18",
        "cordova-android": "~6.3.0"
      },
      "config": {
        "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
        "typescript": "2.4.2"
      },
      "description": "An Ionic project",
      "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
          "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
          "cordova-plugin-device": {},
          "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
          "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
          "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
          "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
          "cordova-plugin-file": {},
          "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
          "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
          "com.synconset.imagepicker": {
            "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "wetry"
          },
          "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {},
          "com-badrit-base64": {},
          "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
          "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
            "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "id "
          },
          "cordova-plugin-analytics": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
          "android"
        ]
      }
    }
```

and this:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+"
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
```

}

Comment: @AndrewLively no not this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a mess with Cordova plugins not specifying dependencies properly in their gradle build files (using different exact versions instead of +).

I'm using this another plugin [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](http://cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release) which somehow fixes the issue for me  (ya...irony it works :D).

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release
ionic cordova platform add android 
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

Above commands will add this plugin, after which you need to re-add android platform.

Edit (other solution):

You can instead try editing the project.properties file with the latest or compatible version (11.+) if the above solution doesn't work

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+
cordova.gradle.include.1=com.synconset.imagepicker/myapp-ignorelinterrors.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=com.synconset.imagepicker/myapp-androidtarget.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.+
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-fcm/myapp-FCMPlugin.gradle
```

Comment: thanks my friend ... work for me

Comment: `using different exact versions instead of +` - specifying `+` pulls in the latest (bleeding edge) version, which may (or may not) be an unstable `alpha` at that point in time.

Comment: Oh..yes. Then could try first with the latest versions 12 or 11.4.+ etc instead of +

Comment: in my case I had to update the lines `cordova.system.library.1=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+`
`cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+` to `cordova.system.library.1=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.+`
`cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.+`

Comment: Thanks! I want to know , What does it happen with this?

Answer (score 1):

i too had this problem , after long research i found out the solution

open the file platform/android/project.properties and check the code

before my code
`cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+`

after my code
`cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.+`

it's working fine ,thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue from yesterday.. 
I have fixed this issue by adding below code in in build.gradle(Module:App(Platforms/android))

```
Add config in android/build.gradle


allprojects {
  repositories {
    ...
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Add force (11.4.0 is version you want to use)
            force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
            force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.0'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ionic cordova platform remove android

ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0
```

Worked for me