# ionic cordova build android error in build

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Yesterday my application build successfully, but today when i bulid my application of firebase, there was some download gradle (ppa) it will give me below error:

OS: **IOS**

```
BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 11.315 secs

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
    > Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    Error: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hardik/projects/firebaseChat/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
    > Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1).
```

Answer (score 0):

In ***platform/android/project.properties*** file change + to 11+

For example:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.+'
}
```

Resources:

1.) [Firebase: Android build error with Error: more than one library with package name ‘com.google.android.gms.license’](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/firebase-android-build-error-with-error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-license/125329/3)

2.) [More than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406185/more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-license)

3.) [ionic3: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405635/ionic3-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-license)